# how should I go about making many reports in the same ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an app that contains a lot of information the few users will want to have reports against.  I might write 10 different reports against the 3 tables involved.  Should I create multiple methods on a report_controller to access each report?

for example I could have a report that is all_to_date or year_over_year_comparison.

I don't know if it would be better to write the reports as separate methods like /reports/report1 and reports/report2 etc or should I create a non database model for the reports an have many different pieces in there?

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider also using Presenters

- http://www.subelsky.com/2008/01/presenter-classes-help-with-rails.html
  and
- https://gist.github.com/1001089

Presenters allow you to extract the logic needed for complex views (especially views that require the use of more than one model) into a separate, easily testable class.  This helps you write clean code and skinny controllers, among other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [statistics gem](https://github.com/acatighera/statistics), it should do what you need.

Comment: That looks like a very handy gem to make it easier to scope just records I need and gather data, thank you.   But I still don't know if it would be better for the different "reports" of information to be accessed via multiple methods in a single controller or some other method.  For example, If I have a /reports#index that has links to 10 reports, should those reports be different methods in the report_controller?  Or should they lead to more controllers?  Or is there a better way that I just don't know yet because I am still new with Ruby?  Thanks for the info on the statistics gem!